# SQL update multiple records with different paramaters or values

Tags: mysql, sql

I know this doesn't work:

```
UPDATE `states` SET `country_id` = '83', `position` = (1,2,3) WHERE `states`.`id` IN (381, 378, 380);
```

Is there a way to update the row based on

```
id = 381; position = 1
id = 378; position = 2
id = 380; position = 3
```

Thanks.

Comment: How do you generate the lists of IDs and positions to update? Are they dyanmically generated from some kind of scoring system? How many of them are there likely to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest is to use three separate queries.

It is possible with a single query, but more complicated:

```
UPDATE states
SET country_id = '83',
    position = CASE id WHEN 381 THEN 1
                       WHEN 378 THEN 2
                       WHEN 370 THEN 3 END
WHERE id IN (381, 378, 380)
```

Comment: One that I could think of is `case`. I am just worried of performance issue because I may have 10's or 20's of items need to be updated at once.