# Updating multiple records with different values in one statement in Ruby

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using Rails 4. Not sure if I am being too ambitious. I have the following example:

```
params[:shop].each_with_index do |id, index|
  Shop.update(id, position: index + 1)
end
```

where `params[:shop] = [1, 3, 5, 7]` is a list of `shop` IDs. The code above should fire 4 separate SQLs like the following:

```
Shop Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  `shops`.* FROM `shops`  WHERE `shops`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  (0.2ms)  BEGIN
SQL (0.5ms)  UPDATE `shops` SET `position` = 1 WHERE `shops`.`id` = 1
Shop Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  `shops`.* FROM `shops`  WHERE `shops`.`id` = 3 LIMIT 1
  (0.2ms)  BEGIN
SQL (0.5ms)  UPDATE `shops` SET `position` = 2 WHERE `shops`.`id` = 3
Shop Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  `shops`.* FROM `shops`  WHERE `shops`.`id` = 5 LIMIT 1
  (0.2ms)  BEGIN
SQL (0.5ms)  UPDATE `shops` SET `position` = 3 WHERE `shops`.`id` = 5
Shop Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  `shops`.* FROM `shops`  WHERE `shops`.`id` = 7 LIMIT 1
  (0.2ms)  BEGIN
SQL (0.5ms)  UPDATE `shops` SET `position` = 4 WHERE `shops`.`id` = 7
```

Is there any way to reduce the SQL to one statement?

Comment: Don't do this on the params hash directly. That's a huge security vulnerability as a malicious user could put something in there that can break your system.

Comment: @MunkiPhD In controller, if *white-listing* done properly... then is there any issue ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit Mind to share it as an answer?

Comment: haha :) one problem there is no `next!`..rather `next` exist.. `index = 0; Shop.update(params[:shop], position: index.next!)`..

Comment: Do one thing... `index_gen = (1...params[:shop].size).each ; Shop.update(params[:shop], position: index_gen.next)`.. try this.

Comment: Calling 'update' once with an array of IDs will still produce 4 SQL update statements, which is specifically what the original question was asking about.

Comment: Why not try then to execute one raw SQL query ? Which DB you are using ?

Comment: Interestingly enough, the same person asked an almost identical question a couple years ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213823/sql-update-multiple-records-with-different-paramaters-or-values?rq=1

Comment: Humm use the `update` query with method `execute`.

Comment: @user980575 Great!! how you searched it out ? Lollz :-)

Comment: @user980575 lol. A lot has changed after 2 years.

Answer (score 0):

There is an `update_all` out there, so that's not your problem. See the documentation [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update_all)

You can do something like:

```
shop_ids = [1,3,5,4]
Shop.where("id in (?)", company_ids).update_all(...)
```

The bigger question is what do you put inside the update_all, since you are basing it on the indexed position of the shop_id in the array. If you know that you just want to bump all of them up or down - you can certainly do that as in

```
shop_ids = [1,3,5,4]
Shop.where("id in (?)", company_ids).update_all("position = position + 1")
```

Other than that - there is probably not much you can do.

Comment: The position is to be `1, 2, 3, 4` with respective of id `1, 3, 5, 41. So if the id is `34, 16, 24, 23`, the position will still be `1, 2, 3, 4` respectively.

Answer (score -1):

This is **not** the answer to the question, but rather, an expansion to my comment about why not to perform the action on the params hash.

White listing simply says to allow certain properties. The reason this is done is to prevent a user from *inserting* properties into the params. Say you are on Posts controller and whitelist everything, a user could insert the following params:

`"user":"123", "password":"abc"`

If you simply update your model using the params hash, you could have just overridden user 123's password to now be 'abc' - a gaping security hole.

If you limit the params strictly to the properties on the Post model, you're reducing the scope to which a user can inflict damage. However, reducing the scope of the damage does not mean prevention.

In the code you provided, you assume that `id` will be a number. What if it isn't? This is where SQL injection becomes an issue*. [See this page for examples](http://rails-sqli.org/). If a user injects malicious SQL, they could get an entire dump of your data, including sensitive information. If you're going to work with the params, be careful.

Additional Resource: [Ruby On Rails Security Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html)

*Rails sanitizes a lot of the data, but some parts are left to sql injection, such as the update_all

Comment: It would be kind of hard to update a password on a user record when you call Shop.update(id, position: value).  The value specified for the ID will be converted to a number, and the position values will be escaped.

Comment: The example of changing a users password was an explanation for white-listing, because yes, you are correct - it wouldn't work for the Update(). I'm merely trying to point out that you have to be careful, because one minor misstep and you could be in a world of hurt.